# Download Image with Extension from URL using cURL php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download GooglePlay app's icons from links provided.

eg. https://lh5.ggpht.com/j0y0xf18PF8iZ_qyKekah11Gg7fteqhqm_VC0SQg7oMsIyMPato7Z_zBsGmOtTf2Fw=w300

now when i am downloading the image, using cURL, using the following code

```
function scaleImageAndSaveIt($appName,$imageURL){
    $format="_%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S";
    $strf=strftime($format);

    $imageLocnName = $appName . $strf ;
    $ch = curl_init($imageURL);
    $fp = fopen($imageLocnName, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $resp;
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    return $imageLocnName; }
```

Now when i am try to save image, i do not have any file extension. (.png, or .jpg or anything else). Though, when i manually save the image, i get the image extension as PNG.

How do i either download the image with default image name and extension or how can I find the extension. Any of the solution would be helpful for me.

Comment: you should check the mime type of the returned file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, and based on the return value decide which extension to use:

```
function GetMimeType($path)
{
    //$type = mime_content_type($file); //deprecated

    /* //file info -> normal method, but returns wrong values for ics files..
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $type = $filename.":".finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    */
    $forbiddenChars = array('?', '*', ':', '|', ';', '<', '>');

    if(strlen(str_replace($forbiddenChars, '', $path)) < strlen($path))
        throw new \Exception("Forbidden characters!");

    $path = escapeshellarg($path);

    ob_start();
    $type = system("file --mime-type -b ".$path);
    ob_clean();
    return $type;
}

function GuessExtension($path)
{
    $type = GetMimType($path);

    $extension = "";
    switch($type)
    {
       case "image/png":
           $extension = ".png";
           break;
        case "image/jpeg":
        default:
           $extension = ".jpg";
           break;
    }
}

//use it like this:

var_dump(GuessExtension("/path/to/your/saved/file"));
```

Comment: It is giving a default return that is .jpg ! when i echo `GetMimeType($path)` it gives output as `application/octet-stream`

Comment: when i run the command `file --mime-type -b filename` in the command line it gives correct filetype that is `image/png`

Comment: Solved it. Problem was at my end. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: @Prashant you are welcome, the default extension is defined in the switch  in case the mime type doesn't match. not sure if this is good or bad.